# gltexcoord[].st doesnt work on new hardware

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Since switching hardware from AMD to Intel, something that worked on AMD seems to cause fatal glsl error on Intel and I had to comment it out:

gltexcoord[0].st is not recognised and breaks the shader.

I am looking for help for an alternative method or maybe a workaround for this piece of code:

```
gl_TexCoord[0].s = r.x / m + 0.5;
gl_TexCoord[0].t = r.y / m + 0.5;

vec4 rS = texture(reflectionSampler, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
```

OpenGL 3.3, GLSL 3.3 - both vertex & fragment shaders 3.30 core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gl_TexCoord` was removed from core profile GLSL. The easiest way to achieve the same effect would be defining output variable `vec2` in vertex shader:

```
out vec2 texCoord;
[..]
texCoord.xy = vec2(r.x / m + 0.f, r.y / m + 0.5);
```

and input variable in fragment shader:

```
in vec2 texCoord;
[..]
vec4 rS = texture(reflectionSampler, texCoord.xy);
```

Comment: Perfect :) Works just like it did before using gl_TexCoord, I've marked your answer! Really appreciate it, thank you!